# Syntax of RenderTransform in c#

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I want to apply render transform property to ellipse but it gives an error.
    I write it as
                   Point p = new Point(100,100);
                   e1.RenderTransform= p;

```
(Error is :Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.Point' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Transform')
Please help as i've a deadline to meet
```

Answer (score 0):

`Point` is not a `Transform`. Typically you would use a `TranslateTransform` for simple repositioning or `CompositeTransform` for standard scale, skew, rotate, translate transform. There are also separate transforms for rotation, scale, skew, a group transform where you can combine multiple transforms together and a generic matrix transform where you need to generate and multiply some matrices to get the expected transformation, but it allows you most freedom especially when manipulating objects on the screen that have already been transformed before.

Comment: could you please tell the syntax of translate transform(how can i use it for positioning element)

Comment: `e1.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = 123, Y = 321 };`